# Instances of images don't show while running apk file, but works well on desktop

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using Android Studio and linux with updated flutter and dart, after compiling desktop version everything is fine, I can see all images.
However when i run apk file on psychical device some images dont't show. I need to change image and setState while program is running, but atm only way to do it is creating image from asset in one command. Please tell my what is good practice in dart to avoid this kind of situations.

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

FileImage fileImage = FileImage(File('images/sample.jpg'));
Image image1 = Image(image: fileImage);

AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage('images/sample.jpg');
Image image2 = Image(image: assetImage);

Image image3 = Image.file(File('images/sample.jpg'));
Image image4 = Image.asset('images/sample.jpg');


return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      image1, // doesn't show when running on android, but shows on desktop
      image2, // doesn't show when running on android, but shows on desktop
      image3, // doesn't show when running on android, but shows on desktop
      image4,                                // works fine on both platfroms
      Image.asset('images/sample.jpg'),      // works fine on both platfroms
      Image.file(File('images/sample.jpg')), // works fine on both platfroms
    ]
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Image 4 because your are getting data from the assetBundle in flutter.

```
Image.asset('images/sample.jpg'),
```

Image 1, 2 , 3 is not working because it is referred to as a File which it is not. If they are working on the desktop because it is in the debug module right now, which flutter inject to resolve some debugging errors. as you generate a published executable file it will not work.